# Why is this a valid way of demonstrating the symmetry of wanna be scalar product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following application on R^3. $\langle u, v \rangle = u^TQv$ where u, v are vectors of R^3 and Q is a 3x3 matrix.

For checking symmetry, the solution in my notes is the following:
$\langle u, v \rangle = u^TQv = (u^TQv)^T = v^TQv = \langle v, u \rangle $

What I have trouble understanding is why do we transpose; what's the logic behind this? How is this a valid way of demonstrating that $\langle u, v \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle$? It seems to me that we did a random operation to force the equality.

Comment: It seems to me that you also need the condition that $Q$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** that 
$$\langle u, v \rangle = u^TQv \\
\langle v, u \rangle = v^TQu $$

To prove the equality you need to show that 
$$u^TQv \stackrel{?}{=} v^TQu$$

Now, if you remember that the transpose of the product is equal with the product of transposes in reverese order, transposing one side of the equality becomes the obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

With the equation $u^TQv = (u^TQv)^T$, we note that $u^TQv$ is equal to its own transpose, which is trivially true since $u^TQv$ is a scalar (or, if you prefer, a $1 \times 1$ matrix).  The reason this is useful is that the transpose respects matrix multiplication in the sense that $(ABC)^T = C^TB^TA^T$ whenever the products $AB$ and $BC$ are defined.

Thus, if $Q$ is symmetric then we have $Q^T = Q$, so we can say that
$$
(u^TQv)^T = v^{T}Q^Tu^{TT} = v^TQu
$$